# What is the easy way to parse an XML In a stored Proc/SQLRPGLE ? Can I use XSLT in Iseries ?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a Stored procedure which receives input as XML. What I need to do it to create the XML into another form which is Suitable for Another system(with the data from the input XML)

I figured out 2 options to do this but both are laborious.
1. Create a DS in the form of the XML and do a 'XML-INTO' to parse data. Then create the new XML 
2. Use XMLTABLE to parse out the data.

Is there a easier way to create the new XML.  A senior in my team suggested to use XSLT. Is this possible in the i?

Comment: I've used xslt on the iseries to convert xml into a csv which I then imported into a table.  Something  like STRQSH xsltproc mytemp.xsl mytarget.xml -o myresult.csv.  I don't bring  source form company to company so I can't be certain of I'm remembering correctly or I would post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT should be available, if nothing else, the IBM i has node.js available and a quick search turned up an XSLT package for node.

Not sure why you find XMLTABLE laborious...and given that it shares the same functions with XSLT, I'd imagine XSLT wouldn't be any better.

You also forgot one option, RPG IV offers the `XML-SAX` op-code also; which obviously uses a SAX parser vs the DOM parser of `XML-INTO`.

With more information about the document, and how you need to pass off the data, we could probably offer more guidance.

Comment: Thanks Charles.. So basically, I am going to get a XML from a third party, Parse it and create a different XML to a different 3rd party.. So Input XML would be received in a Stored Proc, I will parse it using a DS... Now the issue is to create a new XML with this data. One way is to Harcode the XML structure(either in the program, or MSGF or IFS ) and use it just to populate The values in the program. But, I was looking for a way to soft code the creation  of XML. Perhaps using XMLForest(Along that lines)...

Comment: Only XMLFOREST I'm familiar with is the SQL function...you could use XMLTABLE to slice the XML into a table and then XMLFOREST and the other XML publishing functions to build your new XML.  Don't see how to get around _hard coding_ the output structure...unless you're wanting to look up a DTD and generate a valid XM for that...  Seems to be overkill unless the DTD changes often...and you'd still need to hard code the map itemno = itemnum or what not...